# Is there a way to get Azure CLI creation commands that match existing resources?

Tags: azure

I'm looking for a way to automatically generate new instances of my manually created Azure resources. The resources already exist and destroying everything + rebuilding with an IaC framework is not an option at this stage. The existing infrastructure is rather simple (a few VMs, networks, network interfaces, disks, etc), nothing too fancy, and should serve as a blueprint for future deployments. I'd be happy with either generating a list of CLI commands that lead to the desired infrastructure or generating code for the Azure Resource Manager for the same purpose. I heard there are native tools to achieve this but could not find anything.

Is there a way to achieve this or do I have to go the error-prone way of manually writing the code, hoping I don't have any mismatch between the configuration of my coded infrastructure and my current infrastructure?

Comment: Have you found a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can [use Azure Portal to export the templates](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal.md) and check see if you ready to use [Bicep - decompile](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-resource-manager/bicep/decompile.md) to refactor variables/parameters practices, and use it as blueprint repository for future deployments (e.g starter- templates etc etc)